# VBA UDF - how to have "unlimited" ByVal parameters?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom Sub. that removes numbers from a column.  It's pretty straightforward, it asks the user (via inputbox) for columns to remove numbers from.  The user can enter "B C D E F" and it'll loop through the columns B,C,D,E,F and remove numbers.

However, I'd like to call this sub from another sub, but without using the inputbox.  I'd prefer to pass my columns into the sub, i.e.

`Call removeNumbers(B,C,D,E,F)`

and it'd run my removeNumbers macro, using those columns.

How would I set up my `removeNumbers` sub to allow for unlimited values to be passed through (sorry if that's not the terminology!).  Since I could have also just done column B.  Or B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,...,ZZ.

I was thinking something like:

`Sub removeNumbers(Optional ByVal x as String, optional ByVal y as String, optional ByVal z as String)`

But that only leaves room for three "passing variables".  How can I create an open-ended one? Something like `Sub removeNumbers(optional ByVal cols() as Array)`?

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

For what it's worth, here's my `removeNumbers` sub:

```
Sub removeNumbers()
Dim ChosenColumn As String
Dim LastRowCol As String, i As Integer, cel, columnArray() As String

ChosenColumn = InputBox("What columns (A,B,C, etc.) would you like to remove numbers from?  Use SPACES, to separate columns")
columnArray() = Split(ChosenColumn)

LastRowCol = InputBox("What column do you want to use to determine the last cell?")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCol).End(xlUp).row
End With

Dim startCell As Range

For i = LBound(columnArray) To UBound(columnArray)
    Debug.Print "Now going through column " & columnArray(i)
    Column2Copy = columnArray(i)
    For Each cel In Range(Cells(1, columnArray(i)), Cells(lastRow, columnArray(i)))
        If IsNumeric(cel.Value) And Not IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then
            cel.Value = ""
        End If
    Next

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim runAgain
runAgain = MsgBox("Run again?", vbYesNo)
If runAgain = vbYes Then
    Call removeNumbers
Else

    MsgBox ("Done!")
End If

End Sub
```

Edit3: For the solution, @Findwindow's link is a great resource for learning how to do this more programatically.  @Rory's answer is a short and sweet solution, so both work. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Batman slacking on job not patrolling Gotham. Downvoted and flagged.

Comment: You could use a range instead and loop through those columns, and the input box would require a range which you can do with application.inputbox

Comment: @findwindow - how do you know this isn't a dummy user to fool those who think I'm not out and about?? ...and anyways, I'm not this bat character!

Comment: `allow for unlimited values to be passed through` [paramarray](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml) perhaps?

Comment: @findwindow - Ooh, that looks promising, I'll check it out.

Comment: Ugh can't find Tim's exact handle but I got that from him. Edit: @TimWilliams ^_^ Thanks Scott.

Comment: @findwindow  - Tim Williams is who you are looking for :)

Comment: Please. Credit should goto Tim ^_^ Edit: I like how we all know which Tim I meant^^

Comment: That page is deceptively dense - but man, am I glad I asked about this, that looks like a great tool/method. Thanks again @TimWilliams and Findwindow!

Comment: Sure. Glad to serve as ambassador for Tim's great wisdom ^_^;

Comment: yeah, looks like findwindow and @TimWIlliams found something there. I need to keep that in my bag o tricks. Never saw it before

Comment: You could also just pass a delimited string and `Split` it as you do with the `Inputbox`

Comment: @Rory - Bam! That's a quick and easy fix for sure, excellent! I don't know how I didn't realize that when I was asking this question...as you noted, I use that very method in the sub :P